# How to update a field's value by 1 laravel

Tags: laravel

I need to update a field value by one and I have done this:

```
UserTestOption::where('user_id', Auth::id())->update(['done' => 'done'+1]);
```

but it's not updating the field's value

Comment: Do you want to increase the value by 1? or just insert 1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [increment](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#increment-and-decrement).

```
UserTestOption::where('user_id', Auth::id())
    ->increment('done');
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please consider accepting the answer :)